# What does taking a mean of A(B) mean?

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean

I have this code:
`hc = mean(h1(nv),2)`. h1 is one column and nv is three columns. the output hc is one column that's the same length as nv. I'm just not sure what the parentheses syntax means or what the 2 in the code indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Matrix-Indexing and Mean Along Second Dimension

This is a case of matrix-indexing, when one array's values are used to retrieve the values of another array at specific indices. In the example below `nv` is used to retrieve the values stored in `h1` at positions `1`, `4` and `5`. The second input parameter `2` in the `mean()` function indicates that the mean of each row should be taken, resulting in a mean value for each row. In this example since there is only one value in each row, the means of each row results in the same vector. If the mean of all the values in the column vector is wanted the second input parameter into the `mean()` function would be 1.

[image: Matrix Indexing Diagram]

```
%Test arrays/matrices%
nv = [1 4 5];
h1 = [7; 8; 2; 9; 4; 3; 2; 1; 5; 11];

%Indexing h1 using the values in variable nv%
h1(nv)

%Taking the mean of each row%
hc = mean(h1(nv),2);
hc
```